# Converting dojo.xhrGet to dojo/request/xhr for Struts2

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have the following code which passes the `code` and `objectIds` to `trailDesignations.action` correctly.

```
            UpdateTrailDesignationGridClass = function(){
            this.updateTrailDesignationGrid = function(){

                var value1 = 35;
                var xhrArgs = {
                        url: "/trails/trailDesignations.action",
                        handleAs: "text",
                        preventCache: true,
                        content: {
                            code: value1,
                            objectIds: "35.36"
                        },
                        load: function(data){
                            featureResultsContent.innerHTML = data;
                        },
                        error: function(error){
                            featureResultsContent.innerHTML = "An unexpected error occurred: " + error;
                        }
                };

                // Call the asynchronous xhrGet
                var deferred = dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);

            };
        };
```

But since `xhrGet` is deprecated I am trying to do the same thing with `dojo/request/xhr` using the following code.

```
        UpdateTrailDesignationGridClass = function(){
            this.updateTrailDesignationGrid = function(){
                var value1 = 35;
                xhr("/trails/trailDesignations.action",{
                    data:{
                        code: value1,
                        objectIds: "35.36"
                    },
                    preventCache: true

                }).then(function(data){
                    featureResultsContent.innerHTML = data;
                },function(err){
                    featureResultsContent.innerHTML = "An unexpected error occurred: " + error;
                });

            };
        };
```

With the new code the data is not passed to the `code` and `objectIds` fields.  I used the same Struts action in both cases.

```
        <action name="trailDesignations" class="gov.mo.dnr.tis.map.TrailDesignations">
        <result name="success" type="stream">
            <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
            <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

I did get information back from `trailDesignations.action`.

Comment: In your browser `developer tools` see what's difference between previous and this http post raw data.

Comment: Dojo itself is deprecated in Struts2 ;)

Comment: What is it replaced with?  I am not using the plug-in.

Comment: You should write {AtSign}RomanC in your comment to alert him.

Comment: @RomanC What is it replaced with?  I am not using the plug-in.

Comment: @YasserZamani How do I use the firefox developer tools to view the http post raw data?

Comment: Before posting, press `Ctrl+Shift+I` then select `Network` tab then select that post request then `Params` tab.

Comment: @ponder275 What do you mean? If you are not using a plugin then how do you load dojo framework?

Comment: @RomanC  The optimized version of Dojo is in my javascript source files in my Java EE project.  I am working in RAD.

Comment: @ponder275 Did you try jquery? The same code could be rewritten. Dojo is not supported by Struts anymore and you have to fix it yourself.

Comment: @RomanC  What would the jquery equivalent of dojo/xhrGet?

Comment: @ponder275 If you are using plugin then better to read this answer that provides details [how to use ajax with jquery in Struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18931471/573032)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use query :{} for passing the payload... you can find the documentation @http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/request/xhr.html
for post request data : {} can be used.

```
xhr("/trails/trailDesignations.action",{
                query:{
                    code: value1,
                    objectIds: "35.36"
                },
                preventCache: true

            }).then(function(data){
                featureResultsContent.innerHTML = data;
            },function(err){
                featureResultsContent.innerHTML = "An unexpected error occurred: " + error;
            });
```