# struts2 JSP Ajax call

Tags: java, ajax, struts2

I'm trying to make a simple AJAX call in Struts2 JSP, but I'm keep getting this error: "The Struts dispatcher cannot be found."
I've checked other similar threads on stackoverflow and it looks like everything is right. Please advise.

web.xml contains

```
   <filter>
        <filter-name>CompressionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>pl.com.source.filter.gzip.GZIPFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

        <filter>
        <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.hp.aso.pg.dw.wwmd.consoles.LoginFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

        <filter>
        <filter-name>Acegi Filter Chain Proxy</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>   

    <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name> 
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param> 
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>contentTypeFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>pl.com.source.wwmd.filter.ContentTypeFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>zkossThemeFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>pl.com.source.wwmd.filter.ZkossThemeFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>userDefineFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>pl.com.source.wwmd.filter.UserDefineFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Acegi Filter Chain Proxy</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<!--        <url-pattern>*.actionOld</url-pattern>-->
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>zkossThemeFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>userDefineFilter</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern> 
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>userDefineFilter</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>         
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern> 
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>contentTypeFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

</filter-mapping>
```

Struts.xml contains

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="default" extends="json-default" namespace="/">
    <action name="sendvaluetoaction" class="pl.com.source.wwmd.action.topsheests.SendAction">
        <result name="SUCCESS" type="json">/index.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

SendAction.java

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class SendAction extends ActionSupport {
    private String name;
    private String msg;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        try {
            setMsg("Hello " + getName());
            System.out.println(msg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "SUCCESS";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
}
```

Ajax Call:

```
function testChange(){
    var name = "test"
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "sendvaluetoaction",
        data : "name=" + name,
        success : function(data) {
            var html = "<br>" + data.msg;
            console.log(html)
        },
        error : function(data) {
            alert("Some error occured.");
        }
    });

}
```

external Libraries used (among many others):

- Maven: commons-lang:commons-lang:2.2
- Maven: org.apache.struts:struts2-core:2.3.14
- Maven: org.apache.struts:struts2-json-plugin:2.5.10

full error message:

```
The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.TagUtils.getStack(TagUtils.java:60)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.StrutsBodyTagSupport.getStack(StrutsBodyTagSupport.java:44)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.AbstractUITag.setDynamicAttribute(AbstractUITag.java:301)
    at jsp_servlet.__404._jsp__tag0(__404.java:162)
    at jsp_servlet.__404._jspService(__404.java:113)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:35)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:489)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:376)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:247)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:630)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:287)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:866)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:709)
    at weblogic.servlet.FileServlet.findSource(FileServlet.java:276)
    at weblogic.servlet.FileServlet.doGetHeadPost(FileServlet.java:180)
    at weblogic.servlet.FileServlet.service(FileServlet.java:162)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at pl.com.source.wwmd.filter.ContentTypeFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeFilter.java:35)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:77)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at pl.com.source.wwmd.filter.UserDefineFilter.doFilter(UserDefineFilter.java:75)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at pl.com.source.wwmd.filter.ZkossThemeFilter.doFilter(ZkossThemeFilter.java:30)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:264)
    at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
    at org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:81)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:108)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:110)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(BasicProcessingFilter.java:178)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:193)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:274)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:148)
    at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3706)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3672)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:328)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1705)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1665)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:652)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
```

Comment: Are you using Struts 2 tags in a JSP without going through an action?

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry, but I don't really get what you mean.

Comment: I'm not sure how to rephrase. Are there JSP pages accessed directly, e.g., the jsp extension is in the URL?

Comment: No, URL does not have jsp extension.

Comment: `    at jsp_servlet.__404._jsp__tag0(__404.java:162)` so I'd disagree. You're hitting a 404, serving a 404 page, and looks like serving a `404.jsp` that isn't going through an action.

Comment: as you probably already know, I'm completely new to Struts. I've been using this tutorial to make an AJAX call: https://www.websparrow.org/struts/how-to-send-data-from-jsp-to-struts-action-class-using-jquery-ajax, but I can't make it work.  Could you please explain what should I do to fix the issue?

Comment: What's the request being made in the network console? You're getting a 404. What happens if you try to got that URL from the browser directly?

Comment: when I try to hit that URL directly from browser I got: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: So you should investigate: (1) that error, (2) why you get a 404.

Comment: This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/18931471/573032